Accessing Swift Documentation and Libraries Directly from macOS Without Xcode
Is there a way to access Swift documentation or Swift libraries directly on macOS without opening Xcode or search the web? I’m wondering if it's possible to access this information through the Developer app or something similar (lighweight) that’s locally available on the machine.
Essentially, can I access Swift resources without launching Xcode, perhaps through Spotlight search or another built-in tool?
So I am referring to this documentation. If there is a way to access this (this means everything in swift from from protocols to every struct and so on) without opening Xcode, or searching the web.



I believe this is exactly what I've been looking for! Is there a way to open this window/app without using Xcode?


re documentations, does this answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361298/how-do-i-download-the-free-swift-programming-language-book-swift-5-edition-fro   to download a book or the Web version, or the DRM free ePub. You could also look at https://www.swift.org/documentation/

@workingdogsupportUkraine Not really, I am trying to get for example the documentation showed when you press Jump to Definition. I'll attach a picture to the actual question.

Please avoid trying to address specific users via question content; it is exceedingly unlikely that they will see it, and irrelevant to others.  Also, in the future, there's a process for editing to clarify why closed questions are on-topic, rather than deleting/reposting them.

maybe you are looking for Swift AST, eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074672/is-there-a-standard-swift-ast-like-there-is-for-javascript. For example https://swift-ast-explorer.com/   also at: https://forums.swift.org/t/a-new-swift-parser-for-swiftsyntax/59813

@RyanM I thought If I tagged them it will be easier, because the edit did not work.

@workingdogsupportUkraine something like swift-syntax, but local, and with current swift name definitions. Looks like swift-syntax is kind of a representation of swift, not swift itself.

Also there is no need for full code like in swift-syntax, the abstraction in the above picture is more than enough, but somehow locally, maybe being access from spotlight search or something, without the need of Xcode, just on macOS. Instead of View, I might look for Int, or Array or something else.

How about using VSCode, with the Swift extension? It's much morel lightweight than Xcode.

You could have a look at
Swift-DocC "is a documentation compiler for Swift frameworks and packages aimed at making it easy to write and publish great developer documentation"

@Sweeper If you can build documentation for the swift language, that would be nice.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I saw a video about DocC, and is about creating your own documentation, which is going to be very helpful in the future, but my question is not about that. Now, in this video he is going to Product>Build Documentation and a window with documentation appears. That is exactly what I was looking for (documentation for the whole language). Is there a way to get that window without opening Xcode?

Sorry don't know, I'm not familiar with any of this.

@workingdogsupportUkraine ???

Try this,
Product->Build Documentations then Product->Show Build Folder in Finder. Then
go the the Product folder, look around for the .docarchive
Then try reading this:  https://devcodef1.com/news/1380761/swift-documentation-without-xcode

@workingdogsupportUkraine Works! Add an answer so I can mark this question as Answered. So basically you need a dummy project somewhere just for the path thing, and then you can just ignore Imported Documentation, and just use the already built in documentation. Also use sudo. In my case was something similar to this: sudo open /Users/yourusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-abcdefg1234/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testapp.doccarchive/

@workingdogsupportUkraine Even easier is to create a small script to access this thing with just a simple command. Btw Imported Documentation can be removed.

Looks like you can even move .doccarchive file, delete the project, and modify its contents through right click on file, and  Show Package Contents. Now the big question is, how to create a .docarchive file without creating a project in the first place? Or maybe how to open the thing (documentation browser) that creates a .docarchifefile.

There is no way to tag users in questions.

To "access Swift documentation or Swift libraries directly on macOS without opening Xcode or search the web"
try this approach; create the documentations using the command line or
using Xcode initially, for example:
Product->Build Documentations, then Product->Show Build Folder in Finder.
Go the the Product folder, look around for the .docarchive.
Then work on the .docarchive either directly or using some supporting
documentation browser/editor or the command prompt.
See also this article:   https://devcodef1.com/news/1380761/swift-documentation-without-xcode
